# Has Anyone faced this Problem: In-Browser code editor not working

Tags: apex, visualforce, editor, browser

Today when I tried opening my page.I'm getting it as

[image]

for both Visualforce and Apex class. Don't know why?

I have to go to the individual page and class to modify any changes and it's disgusting
Any Solution for this. I tried in different Browsers and the same issue in all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the browser cache and cookies. Read this for more info: [Where did the line numbers go (browser editor)?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11590/where-did-the-line-numbers-go-browser-editor)

Comment: I have same issue, cleaning cache is not working. Looking at the Chrome console I can see 2 critical files are not found (404) javascript/labels?lang=en_US 404 (Not Found) and /components/codeeditor.css 404 (Not Found)... Where could I report this issue ?

Comment: You need to clear realy all the data (select `beginning of time` to delete everything)! https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?hl=en

Comment: you were right :), I dont trust any more to my cache plugin